# Ion-input inside ion-item with text-end attribute within Ionic 3.9.2

Tags: angular, typescript, input, ionic2

I want to use an ion-input inside an ion-item with the text align right.
However, it is done, but when scrolling the page, the content in the input has been kept swinging.

GIF of content been kept swinging:

[image: gif of content been kept swinging]

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-item class="required">
    <ion-label fixed>label name</ion-label>
    <ion-input text-end clearInput></ion-input>
  </ion-item>   
</ion-content>
```

What should I do for this case?
Is there an other way for me to use an ion-input which the content align right?

Comment: Did these help? http://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/

Comment: Yes , but this may get swinging when scrolling the page.As shown in the GIF.